# Combine SingleChildScrollView and PageView in Flutter

Tags: flutter, scrollable, pageviews

I created two forms, and added them to a PageView. Each form has 6 TextFormField. When I tap on the last 2 TextFormField, the keyboard shows up over these fields and hides them. What I need is to scroll up the form to show these fields when I tap each one and the keyboard is visible.
For this approach I tried using a SingleChildScrollView under PageView like in the example, but it doesn't do what I need.
How can I fix this?

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
        body: PageView(
            children: <Widget>[
            _sampleForm(),
            _sampleForm(),  
            ],
        ),
    )
}

_sampleForm(){
    return Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 10),
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                    Form(
                        child: Column(
                            children: <Widget>[
                                TextFormField(...),
                                TextFormField(...),
                                TextFormField(...),
                                TextFormField(...),
                                TextFormField(...),
                                TextFormField(...),
                            ],
                        ),
                    ),
                ],
            ),  
        ),
    );
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have tested this to work.

```
class SO extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SOState createState() => _SOState();
}

class _SOState extends State<SO> {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(""),
      ),
      body: PageView(
        children: <Widget>[
          _sampleForm("Page 1"),
          _sampleForm("Page 2"),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  _sampleForm(String title) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(32.0),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Form(
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  ListTile(title: Text(title, textAlign: TextAlign.center)),
                  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) TextFormField(decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "field ${i+1}"),),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

---

Just some extra padding to show the content is what you need.

Comment: @sfirc Why did you accept the answer. It make no sense at all. Padding will note enable scrolling.